# Xcode 4.2 Codesign

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, xcode4, xcode4.2

I keep getting this error and i have been trying everything for about a week is there anything that you guys known about this.

Its only a warning that comes up when i archive my app but it still come up with build successed and i can still validate so do you think i could send it to iTunes connect still or will they just fail it thanks in advanced.

my error

[image]

Here is my code sign at the moment

[image]

this is a update on what my code sign looks like in project build settings and targets build settings still don't no what wrong but i still get the same warning?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the menu:

**Product -> Edit Scheme -> Archive**

The action should be **Distribution**

Also you just need to set the Codesign in the "Any iOS SDK" field.

Something like this:

### [image: Codesign]

Comment: ok i have already done the scheme just so what do i put in the code sign can you upload load photo or tell me please buddy

Comment: please buddy i am pulling my hair out as we speak

Comment: I think it's just the codesigning bit I need to no which ones each one (full dicribtion) thanks

Comment: @annu look at my question thats what i have at the moment I've updated it

Comment: @user1358719 have u tried to recreate that distribution profile?

Comment: its all good now i did what you said and it works thank you very much